# How to know if a tag contains a value or another tag?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using DOM representations in java

how can I distinguish if an xml tag has a value inside it or has another embedded tag ?
For example, I can have :

```
<item> 2 </item>
```

or

```
<item> <name> item1 </name> </item>
```

i want to do the following

```
if(condition1 : there is no tags inside item tag) do ...
else  do ...
```

how can I write condition 1 ?

Comment: [childElementCount](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-childElementCount): `x.childElementCount` (where `x` is a reference to your element). If it returns zero, the element has no child elements.

Comment: @Šime Vidas That hasn't made it into the Java implementation of the DOM API yet, has it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just test every child by iterating over the list of child nodes:

```
public static boolean hasChildElements(Element el) {
    NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

condition1 is then `(! hasChildElements(el))`.

Alternatively, you can implement the test with [`getElementsByTagName("*").getLength() == 0`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)). However, if there *are* sub elements, this method will traverse the whole fragment you're testing, and allocate lots of memory.

Answer (score 2):

ElementNodes have a [getElementsByTagName method](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-A6C9094). Call it with the string `'*'` as the argument (to match *all tag names*) then count the number of results. More than zero and there are child elements.

Comment: If called on the root of a large document this will take a long time and allocate lots of memory though.

Answer (score 1):

```
NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("item");
nl.getChildNodes();
```

You can iterate over childNodes to get the nodeType if nodeType is text you can put your condition.