# How to know if a xml node contains a value or another node?

Tags: java

Here is my XML

```
    <action>
    <name>EDIT</name>
    <type>123</type>
    <services>
        <service>
         this is child node
        </service>
    <services>
 </action>
```

The above XML is having root node  and having childNode  ,  ,   , so we want to find childNodes  having any childNodes or having text , so to find it we have written below java code to parse it

```
File fXmlFile = new File("/opt/staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("action");
        // for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < nList1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nList1.item(i);
            NodeList childNodeList = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int childCount = 0; childCount < childNodeList.getLength(); childCount++) {
                Node gChild = childNodeList.item(childCount);                   
                if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE != childNodeList.getNodeType()) {
                    continue;
                } // end of if

                if(gChild.hasChildNodes()){
                     System.out.print("having child node ");
                }else{
                     System.out.print("not having child node ");
                }
            }//end Of For
        }//end Of For
```

so when we execute above code it should print out put like this

```
not having child node
not having child node
having child node
```

because `<name>` and `<type>` nodes not having childNode and `<services>` node is having childNode but it is printing output like this

```
having child node
having child node
having child node
```

when i google about this problem i got below link and i have tried but my problem not solved
[How to know if a tag contains a value or another tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641398/how-to-know-if-a-tag-contains-a-value-or-another-tag)
can any one help me

Comment: All 3 elements (`<name>`, `<type>`, and `<services>`) have child nodes, because text is in a [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Text.html) node, so your code is correctly printing that all of them have child nodes. Did you mean to check if they have [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) children?

Comment: yes we want to know whether <name> , <type> and <services> having Children Element